# AngularJS custom directive scope not reflecting

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope

I have a custom directive called crust:
JS:

```
 .directive('crust', function(){
                return{
                    restrict: 'EA',
                    replace: true,
                    scope: {       
                      datasource: '=' 
                    },
                    templateUrl: '../../configurator/partials/crust.html'
                }
            })
```

HTML template `(crust.html)`:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="type in datasource.types">
  <input type="radio" 
    name="{{datasource.id}}" 
    data-ng-class="radio-selector" 
    data-ng-true-value="true" 
    value="true" 
    data-ng-model="type.selected" 
    data-ng-change="updatePizza(type)" 
    id="{{type.id}}">
  <label for="{{type.id}}"> <span></span>
    <h2 data-ng-bind="type.name"></h2>
    <p data-ng-bind="type.description"></p>
  </label>
</li>
```

The Model (crustTypes) is pulled via a service from this JSON:

```
{
    "id": "crt",
    "types": [{
        "id": "crt1",
        "name": "original",
        "description": "Our traditional scratch-made crust",
        "price": "5",
        "selected":"false"
    }, {
        "id": "crt2",
        "name": "thin",
        "description": "A light crispier crust",
        "price": "6",
        "selected":"false"

    }, {
        "id": "crt3",
        "name": "fresh pan",
        "description": "A thick buttery crust",
        "price": "7",
        "selected":"false"
    }, {
        "id": "crt4",
        "name": "stuffed",
        "description": "Two layers of original crust",
        "price": "8",
        "selected":"false"
    }]
}
```

The directive is being invoked in the HTML like so:

```
<ul>
 <crust data-datasource="crustTypes" data-datavalue="pcrustType"></crust>
</ul>
```

The looping is working fine, and ng-repeat is rendering the list properly. The problem is that I want to assign `datasource.id` as the common name of the radio group, and due to some reason, `datasource.id` is coming up as undefined. Consequently, the name is not being assigned and the user is being allowed to enter multiple selections.

If instead I pass `type` to `updatePizza(item)` it comes up fine. Its just the parent model that's not being displayed

If I try to return `datasource` through `updatePizza()`, it is still coming up as undefined.

I'm sure I'm missing something basic here. Help!

Here is a [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/p6mhkp60rGJkvkJU0xi2/preview) of the code

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using?

Comment: @CalebWilliams 1.4.5

Comment: What does a `console.log($scope.datasource)` look like?

Comment: I'm passing it back to the controller, and in the `updatePizza(item)` function, `console.log($scope.datasource)` says `undefined` but if instead I pass `type` to `updatePizza(item)` it comes up fine. Its just the parent model that's not being displayed

Comment: OK, I thought it might be an issue with Angular 1.2.x, but it wasn't. Could you post a plunk of this and I can take a look at it?

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/p6mhkp60rGJkvkJU0xi2/preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `name="{{datasource.id}}"` with `name="{{$parent.datasource.id}}"`